# How to create a custom form?

Tags: forms, static-block, contact-us, contact-form

I am trying to create a create a page in block but I'm trying to add a custom contact form. I can view it in frontend but it wouldn't work its not doing anything when I click submit.

is there anyone who could help me out or any suggestions

Is it good to create a new module for custom form?

How I'm calling the .phtml in CMS block

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="my_module::form.phtml"}}
```

but not sure why `action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>` isn't working in .phtml

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try this {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="My_Module::form.phtml"}}. You have added ( and ) at the start and end of code.

Comment: @SukumarGorai what you mean by this ("You have added ( and ) at the start and end of code.")

Comment: At the start of your code there is bracket "(" and end ")". Remove those.

Comment: </div>
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="newContactForm" template="Limitless_HelpCenterContactForm::form.phtml"}}</div>
</div> this si what i have i dont have the brackets()

Comment: the person who edited this add them brackets in

Comment: Don't add screenshot as an answer. Add it to your question. Can you inspect element and take a screenshot of your form?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, how do i add the screenshot as a comment rather than a answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94909/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-jibin-george).

Answer (score 1):

i have tried creating controller. but no result this is the form i have created even if i click submit i am not even getting no error message. @ Khushbu
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create controller as explained in 
   [Create controller](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html)
2. Give link of that controller in your form action.
3. In controller **execute()** method you can get posted data as below:

```
$data=$this->getRequest()->getParam('inputname');
```

4. Do required processing with received data.

Comment: I have tried this now but no result same as before

Comment: Do you get redirected to controller page or not?

Comment: i dont have no redirect, the form isn't working l no error message when i press submit